# Datatables export in Excel and nested tables inside a cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable where some cell has inside it another table.

```
<table id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>
               <table style="width:100%">
               <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>COL 1</th>
                 <th>COL 2</th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td>value 1</td>
                   <td>value 2</td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

When I export to EXCEL, the problem is that cell is exported as a SINGLE LINE like this:

```
COL 1        COL 2            value 1             value 2
```

Is there a way to force to insert some basic formatting to that cell to get newline and separate every subcell with a `-` ?

```
COL 1 - COL 2
value 1 - value 2
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h63w7xo0/1/

Answer (score -2):

Why do you have a nested table? Maybe that's confusing the Excel

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>
               <table style="width:100%">
```

Comment: I need nested tables in my app. That's it